# Why is FTP server slowing down the web server?

Tags: web-server, web-hosting, ftp

I am running Apache and Filezilla ftp server in Windows. I've been noticing for the last few months that whenever I start up the ftp server, the websites start to run slow. When I shut off the ftp server, the websites start speeding up again. Sometimes I need to restart Apache server after shutting off the ftp server to speed up the websites. I only start ftp server whenever I need to allow remote file transfers. Other than that it's always off. I'm not sure what's happening and where to look.

Comment: Why run Apache and Filezilla on Windows?  Run Linux apps on Linux, and Windows apps on Windows to make your life much easier.  The Windows program you're looking for is called IIS, by the way, and allows both you to serve up web and ftp.

Comment: Is there a reason you *can't* run IIS for this? There's really no way for us to know why filezilla is making your system slow (the number of potential causes are infinite - you need to troubleshoot on your end and narrow the field some...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many possible reasons for this.  To start with, if you are running them on the same server you will be effectively dividing the resources between the two applications.  The FTP and Apache servers will need to share CPU time, memory usage and bandwidth.  For example, if an upload/download is occurring to the FTP server it would be utilizing the bandwidth and may cause apache to appear to respond slower.

If you are running this on a Linux/Unix server try using the `top` command to monitor CPU and memory usage.  For network utilization try looking at the `netstat` command.  If you are using windows, look at the `task manager` to observe network, CPU and memory utilization.